# Snap face bottom

Tags: modeling

I use different option but I can't snap face bottom to the cube's edge.
You can see here the result. How do I do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the very useful **Snap with Active** vertex:

From the snapping dropdown select the **Snap to Vertex** and **Snap with Active**. This will snap the *active vertex* to any other vertex in the mesh that you drag your mouse over. The active vertex will be the vertex that is selected last.

[image]

In vertex select mode select the face then to make one of the vertices of the lower edge "active" hold down the Shift key while deselecting then re-selecting this vertex. The active vertex will now show as white.

[image]

Drag the selected face down along the Z axis, **G**  **Z** and hold down the **Ctrl** key (Ctrl key will enable snapping) when you now hover your mouse cursor over one of the vertices that make up the lower edge, the *active vertex* will snap to that vertex (constrained in the Z axis).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by enabling *snap to edges* in edit mode. I achieved [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FLEv.png) when doing so. You have *snap to increments* enabled, so just switch that from increments to edges.